# Copper density modification

Tags: physical-chemistry, density, metals, isotopes

Can you increase the density of a material surface (metal) by surface treatment?
For example commercial copper. If we take the ordinary OF copper (99.95%), I would expect not to have the tabulated 8.92/8.96 g/m$^3$. Probably the OFE copper (99.99%) would be really close to those values.

So my question is if by applying heating and quenching to the material surface would this increase it`s density? And I would mainly think about removing the impurities (oxygen) in a hydrogen reducing atmosphere.

Furthermore, copper appears to have two main isotopes $^{63}$Cu and $^{65}$Cu, with the later in a 30% proportion. So I would expect that if you can increase the proportion of the $^{65}$Cu you would also increase the density.

Comment: You asked basically the same question a few days ago. Why is this one any different?

Comment: check here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/metal-surface-density-increase

Comment: because that one was on hold and it appeared that nobody is moderating it anymore.... or yes? however - now is closed.

Comment: do you want to increase the density of the surface only, or the whole thing?

Comment: I guess the Chem people are more familiar with surface treatment or purifying a metal?..

Comment: A side question: can a copper be coated with copper using surface treatment?<br> Also, can heating be done to remove the oxygen from the surface only?

Comment: I would be glad to increase the density of the surface only, or subsurface, and even in a randomly way. Homogeneity is not critical, although would be nice to have some consistent surface density. So even if I would create some imperfections in the surface which could lead to some localized density increase would be a start.

Comment: Purifying the metal is quite costly process, since should be done with Czochralski process. The Japanese achieved 9N purity but probably the price is huge. And this would not guarantee a higher density than the tabulated one (8.96).

Comment: During annealing (vacuum in H atmosphere) I would expect to reduce the oxygen at least on the surface, unless that in the bulk will diffuse and replenish the vacancies.

Comment: How about dipping the lower density copper in a melted copper with higher density/purer?

Comment: Well since I am not aware of any method of producing high-purity(denser) copper than the single crystal growth, it would not make sense to dip it (if you would have how to) in a crystal furnace....

Comment: There's also the electrolysis method of purifying copper, but I'm not sure the surface would be denser..

Comment: According to my knowledge the electrolysis would yield only 4N grade in best case scenario. So that would be the expensive OFE grade copper.

Answer (score 0):

Copper is quite a dense metal at 8.96. Both the stable copper oxides are lower density. I do not believe any surface treatment could increase the bulk density of pure copper, unless there are cavities in the material. The only way apparent density might increase is if the volume is assumed constant and the treatment causes the surface to adsorb external gases to a greater extent.

Comment: Agree with the adsorbed (chemisorbed most likely) gases, but these would modify the purity. And yet hard to believe the volume would remain constant while reasonable amounts of impurities are introduces in the lattice. And by introducing this impurities are we not creating more dislocations which possible could reduce the density by increasing the volume?

Answer (score 0):

There's a type of alloy called interstitial alloy, which might increase the density of the metal, while perhaps not expanding its volume, by introducing small atoms that can fit

[image]

Comment: It would increase the density but would it be still copper? I would like to know if there is a way to increase the density of OF grade copper. Because like that one can introduce osmium atoms in the copper and the problem would be solved

Comment: In that case, removing oxygen from the copper might not do, because these are the small atoms that occupy the interstitial spaces

Comment: Are you sure they occupy the interstitial spaces? This looks to be in the case of trapped oxygen. I would say oxygen is in form of copper oxide (I or II) which damage the FCC structure of the "ideal" copper thus decreasing the density.

Comment: Then by removing it, you might just make the density even, since copper oxide might be just on the surface and the rest of the oxygen is trapped oxygen. And I'm not sure it would make the copper more crystalline.

Comment: And the sample should be in vacuum to prevent further oxidation on surface. So it seems there is no clear way how to improve the surface density....